# Uri null after null check - SMS Content provider [Android SDK 30+]

Tags: android, sms, messaging, telephonymanager, android-sms

```
    public void save(AppCompatActivity context, SMSListener listener) {
    mContext = context;
    try {
    //  String mode = SMSData.getSMS_typeText(type_internal);
        ContentValues values = returnContentValues(); // content values
        ContentResolver resolver = context.getContentResolver();
        Uri uri = Telephony.Sms.CONTENT_URI;
        if (resolver != null && uri != null)
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
                ContentProviderClient client =
                        resolver.acquireContentProviderClient(Telephony.Sms.CONTENT_URI);
                client.insert(uri, values);
                client.release();
            } else {
                resolver.insert(uri, values);
            }
        else {
            listener.onCompleted(false);
            return;
        }
        listener.onCompleted(true);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        listener.onCompleted(false);
    }
```

So, this is the code I've wrote till now trying to write SMS content provider which is working well when targeting SDK Level of <30, but for >= 30, it's throwing the below exception. (***tried to insert directly with Contentresolver too instead of ContentProviderClient, but the exception was same! on 30+***)

```
System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.net.Uri.getAuthority()' on a null object reference
System.err:     at android.os.Parcel.createExceptionOrNull(Parcel.java:2379)
System.err:     at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:2357)
System.err:     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2340)
System.err:     at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:190)
System.err:     at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:142)
System.err:     at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.insert(ContentProviderNative.java:549)
System.err:     at android.content.ContentProviderClient.insert(ContentProviderClient.java:348)
System.err:     at android.content.ContentProviderClient.insert(ContentProviderClient.java:337)
System.err:     at xxxxx.zzzz.dddd.save(SMSCreator.java:94)
```

I've already checked the authority for SMS content resolver isn't null (by writing a test code), then I came to know about the package-visibility related issues in Android Q, so I included this in manifest & included `QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES` too:

```
<queries>
    <package android:name="string" />
    <provider
        android:authorities="list"
        android:exported="false" />
</queries>
```

Just to be sure I also run some bunch of code that prints the authorities of SMS providers and the output included :

```
[content://sms, content://sms-changes, content://mms-sms]
```

I've also made the app default SMS app with all the required permissions. What am I missing so the code isn't working in Android Q+?

[edit] Also I checked the neither Uri nor it's authority value is null then why getAuthority() is throwing null? I've used the similar code to [Google's messaging app](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Messaging/+/78ecab8743c01b13b628432049fde5eaca568d2d/src/com/android/messaging/sms/MmsUtils.java#858), still the same result.

**UPDATE** : Though I've done null check on the uri, it says on a Android 10 device

```
W/System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException: Uri must not be null
W/System.err:     at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:2077)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2039)
W/System.err:     at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:188)
W/System.err:     at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:140)
W/System.err:     at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.insert(ContentProviderNative.java:481)
W/System.err:     at android.content.ContentProviderClient.insert(ContentProviderClient.java:318)
W/System.err:     at xxxxx.zzzz.dddd.save(SMSCreator.java:94)
```

(using Pixel 5/Moto One)

Comment: did u get an uri? or just get null? because u can just get an incorrect uri path

Comment: The URI isn't null, I've checked it, but running `insert` says it's null, only when targetSDK is 30+

Comment: this is probably related to the new permission restrictions but I can't find a single posts about this anywhere.

Comment: i think i know what permission u need to use, i’ll write an answer

Comment: Hello @exploitr, did you find a solution for this error?

Comment: @BrookMG Nah man, I gave up as I'm busy with some irl stuff, but I'd recommend looking at https://github.com/moezbhatti/qksms

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this permission

```java
mActivity.getActivityResultRegistry().register("key", new ActivityResultContracts.OpenDocument(), result -> {
                        mActivity.getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().takePersistableUriPermission(
                                result,
                                Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION
                        );
```

Comment: It didn't work, same problem. I'm reading the code of this application to find out what they did, but they're running the same code apparently and somehow it's working. I'll be doing more research : https://github.com/moezbhatti/qksms